# Dynamically change the content of the div using anchor tags angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm having a problem on how to load a dynamic view using Angularjs in anchor tags. By the way I can't use ng-view since ng-view can only be use once in a template. So I'm thinking of using the ng-src but on the sample docs it is using a select element tag and fetching its values to the controllers. What I want is when I click a link say the View1, the content of my div will change. I will explain further.

Say I have this 3 anchor tags

```
<li><a href="#/view1">View1</a></li>
<li><a href="#/view2">View2</a></li>
<li><a href="#/view3">View3</a></li>
```

Before

```
 <div data-ng-include="" data-ng-src="default.html"></div>
```

Now when I click #/view1

```
 //the ng-src of the html will change depending on the link clicked
 <div data-ng-include="" data-ng-src="view1.html"></div>
```

Comment: `ng-view` does the same. Read the documentation on **$route** and **$routeProvider**.

Comment: @Codezilla, I can't use anymore the ng-view since I already used it on my other partial views. I think ng-view can only be use once per template. right?

Comment: `ng-src` is usually attributed to an `img` tag.  Are you looking for `ng-include`?

Comment: @DavinTryon, yes i'm thinking of using ng-include the achieve a dynamic view just like ng-view. Don't know how to implement it though using angular T__T

Comment: @WonderingCoder Oops! I did not read the question carefully. You can take a look at my answer given below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you are trying to do something as below:

**HTML:**

```
<!-- Dont use # in the hrefs to stop the template from reloading -->
<li><a href="" ng-click="selectedTemplate.path = 'view1.html'">View1</a></li>
<li><a href="" ng-click="selectedTemplate.path = 'view2.html'">View2</a></li>
<li><a href="" ng-click="selectedTemplate.path = 'view3.html'">View3</a></li>

<div data-ng-include="selectedTemplate.path"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
$scope.selectedTemplate = {
    "path":"view1.html"
};
```

Comment: It is not even necessary to have the `JS` if you don't want a controller.  The `selectedTemplate.path` will add to the current scope. http://jsfiddle.net/davintryon/sL7Lm/

Comment: @DavinTryon I think the JS is important in case where you would have all the `li`s within ng-repeat or something that would create a different scope.

Comment: True, just a comment that it will work without it for simple cases.

Answer (score 1):

ng-view is the main view of any Angular app, and is affected by the route changes. So all you anchor tags will only affect the ng-view template.

To load other partial views based on the main ng-view, ng-include is the correct way to go as you have mentioned already.

To load a view based on the main view (view shown in ng-view), you need to write mapping logic which depending upon the main view should load other partials (ng-include elements for page).

So your partial becomes like

```
<div data-ng-include='templateNameVariable'></div>
```

This variable has to be set whenever the ng-view changes on location change.

You can watch for `$route` `$routeChangeSuccess` event and change the `templateNameVariable` based on the active route (hence the view).

So there should a controller out side the ng-view directive which will orchestrate this, and you would do

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess',function(event,current,previous) {
     //Change the templateNameVariable to point to correct template here, based on current route.
});
```